# How does $scope.$on work and $destroy get invoked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Can anyone please explain about the working of `$scope.$on` and how does `$destroy` work in these two controllers. Like when I change the route, a different controller gets called, is that why `$destroy` gets invoked?
And how does the `$interval` get initialized, i have just defined it as a variable under promiseA, yet it gets initialized. I just copied these lines to fulfill the requirement, can anyone please help me understand these lines of codes?

```
        var myApp=angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
        myApp.controller('myController',function($scope){


        });
        myApp.controller('firstPage',function($scope,$interval){

            $scope.thisMessage="First Message";
            $scope.firstcall=function(){
                var promiseA=$interval(function(){

                        console.log("First Page");
                    },10000);
                $scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
                    $interval.cancel(promiseA);
                });
            }
            });
        myApp.controller('secondPage',function($scope,$interval){
            $scope.thisMessage="Second Message";

            $scope.thisMessage="Second Message";
            $scope.secondcall=function(){
                var promiseB=$interval(function(){

                        console.log("Second Page");

                },10000);
                $scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
                    $interval.cancel(promiseB);
                });
            }
        });

        myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider.when("/",{
                templateUrl:"First.html"
                })
            .when("/second",{
                templateUrl:"Second.html"
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short using `$scope.$on` you can add listeners (subscribe) for angular's internal events and also custom events which you can trigger yourself using the [$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) and [$broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) services. The `$destroy` itself is an event which gets triggered when a controller is being destroyed, so you have a hook if you maybe want to save some data or whatever you'd like to do.

You can find more information about this kind of stuff in the Angular's documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on).

Given the fact that each of your route has a different controller when you are switching through the routes you are instantiating one and destroying the other (which triggers the `$destroy` event which you are listening for).

I also recommend you check out `$off` method, which is the way you can unsubscribe from the events, avoiding memory leaks and strange behaviour. Unfortunately I couldn't find any docs about that but how it basically works is, you subscribe for an event like this:

```
$scope.$on('customEvent', someFunction);
```

And you unsubscribe like this:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.$off('customEvent', someFunction);
});
```

Keep in mind that you do not really have to unsubscribe inside the `$destroy` listener but I think it's a best practice to do so.

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks a lot